# Get img from php and reload

Tags: php, image

Hello i have a php file that is dynamically creating images. Basically its adding a text on the`img` . Im calling them like this in the html without problems

```
<img src="img.php?session=<?php echo $session; ?>" />
<img src="img.php?session=<?php echo $session; ?>" />
```

Now if the image on the server change and i call this again from the html the image doesnt change, i have to do a full page refresh in order to see the new image.
[EDIT] Ive also noticed that it works ok on Chrome. I have this problem at firefox only, its like igonring the `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache/>`

Comment: is the image loading when you refresh the page? in that case you could add some javascript to your `<img>` tag to reload the page. as such: `onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href"` or `onClick="window.location.reload()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I adopted is the following one.

```
var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
<img src="img.php?session=<?php echo $session; ?>&time=' + ts + '" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have to do with your PHP but with your browser. The browser is caching the image, thus the need for a full refresh. You should be able to fix this by adding this between your HTML `head` tags

```
 <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
```

**EDIT**
Looks like there is an other `http-equiv` that could do the same thing:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

Comment: can you post all of your HTML as well then?

Answer (score 1):

You could add `No Cache` headers to the image using `header()`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a random number at the end of the image source, then it will always get the image from the server because it can not be found in the cache.